# Given $\tan\theta=7/9$ and $\cos\theta<0$, find $\tan(\theta/2)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Given $\tan\theta=7/9$ and $\cos\theta<0$, find $\tan(\theta/2)$.

Since the angle is lying on quadrant 3, I got 
$$\cos\theta=-9/\sqrt{130}$$
and substitute it in 
$$\tan(\theta/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$
However, there is a negative sign in the final answer
$$\tan(\theta/2)=-\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{9}{\sqrt{130}}}{1-\frac{9}{\sqrt{130}}}}$$
I know when we square root a number, there will have a plus or minus sign outside the square root, but I don't know why it pick the negative one in this case.

Comment: because you know $\theta/2$ should be lying in quadrant  2

Comment: Oh yes, I have made a mistake on here XD
I mixed up $$(\pi+(\theta/2)) \text{ and }(\theta/2)$$
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Using $t$-formula**

Let $t=\tan \dfrac{\theta}{2}$,

\begin{align*}
  \tan \theta &= \frac{2t}{1-t^2} \\
  \frac{2t}{1-t^2} &= \frac{7}{9} \\
  7t^2+18t-7 &= 0 \\
  t &= \frac{-9\pm \sqrt{130}}{7} \\
  \cos \theta &= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\
  \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} &< 0 \\
  t^2 &> 1
\end{align*}

Rejecting $t = \dfrac{-9+\sqrt{130}}{7}$, we have

> $$\tan \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{-9-\sqrt{130}}{7}$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a straightedge and compasses?  If so:  draw an angle in a coordinate plane with vertex at the origin, one leg along the positive $x$ axis and the other leg in the third quadrant.  Then construct the bisecting line, drawing it in both directions from the origin.  What is the slope of the line; what quadrants does it pass through?

You infer the sign from the quadrant of $\theta$.  For $\theta$ in the third quadrant, $\theta/2$ is in the second or fourth quadrant (which we see in the exercise above), so its tangent must be negative.

Answer (score 1):

When you solve (in radians):

$$\tan\left(\theta\right)=\frac{7}{9}\Longleftrightarrow\theta=n\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)$$
Where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

When we substiute that into $\cos\left(\theta\right)$:
$$\cos\left(n\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{9}{\sqrt{130}}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{is}\space\text{even}\\
-\frac{9}{\sqrt{130}}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{is}\space\text{odd}
\end{cases}$$

When we substiute that into $\sin\left(\theta\right)$:
$$\sin\left(n\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{7}{\sqrt{130}}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{is}\space\text{even}\\
-\frac{7}{\sqrt{130}}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{is}\space\text{odd}
\end{cases}$$

So, when $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{1+\cos\left(\theta\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(n\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)\right)}{1+\cos\left(n\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)\right)}=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{130}-9}{7}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{is}\space\text{even}\\
-\frac{9+\sqrt{130}}{7}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{is}\space\text{odd}
\end{cases}$$